# How to fix/reinstall grub from debian media, e.g. rescue mode?

Tags: debian, grub2, system-installation, uefi, rescue

How can one invoke `grub-install` from the debian netinst image? Or, does one need the live cd.

(Situation: two disks: one degraded btrfs raid 1, another a blank disk I can install a new OS on, but which I can't boot from due to mobo. Currently upon booting, a black screen says "[Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304144/clean-install-of-ubuntu-wont-boot-reboot-and-select-proper-boot-device)"; which program is saying this? Is this a GRUB message I can't find in the sourcecode? What is it trying to say; is it "failing successfully" or failing at a certain point?)

I started the 'rescue' mode, selected "launch shell" (no root partition) when prompted, it set up a shell, but the only command is called `grub-installer` (not `grub-install`) which doesn't seem to do anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this own question:

- installed linux on a new partition on the unbootable disk
- selected that as the active root partition in the debian graphical rescue
- did grub-install on the bootable disk, /dev/sda
- confirmed by doing `efibootmgr /dev/sda -v`, then checking the grub being pointed to was the one in the appropriate partition by checking `ls -l /dev/disk/by-partuuid`

The BootOrder can be set with the appropriate options in `efibootmgr -h` it seems (compare with first line of verbose output).

It seems, barring some strange way to bootstrap up a system in RAM from the netinst image, that you might need a live CD or USB, or to install an OS (which you can't do from a USB to itself).

**Further question:**

If someone knows how to install a fallback (to say the grub on `/dev/sda1` that is not being detected), if they could post their own answer (or edit this and make it community wiki, or post a comment), that would be great thank you.